# Heroku access remote postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have an heroku app and 3 different databases on 3 different servers (including localhost)

I tried to connect to each of them and i always get

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
```

My DATABASE_URL is correct and the app runs smoothly with heroku's native database

At first i thought it was the firewall from my hostings but i created a localhost db, opened both 5432 and 5433 ports and still heroku can't connect... i submited a ticket but no response so far.

Can someone help me?

**database.yml**

```
 development:
port: 5432
host: host
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: database
pool: 5
username: user
password: pass

 test:
port: 5432
host: host
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: database
pool: 5
username: user
password: pass

production:
port: 5432
host: host
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: database
pool: 5
username: user
password: pass
```

Comment: Could you please post your config/database.yml? (remove any credentials in there first please)

Comment: edited the question, however i think heroku doesnt even care about database.yml because he connects only through that DATABASE_URL in the settings... even if i have a wrong database.yml but connect to the native heroku db through DATABASE_URL it works fine

Comment: In Rails the `DATABASE_URL` env var overrides any settings in `config/database.yml`. Did you try setting it from the heroku dashboard?

Comment: i did... and he tries to connect correctly... but he never actually makes it... i thought it might be firewall blockage on the servers but 3 servers... and localhost with ports open...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your port is closed. To open it on an Ubuntu machine use the commands below.

```
sudo ufw allow 5432
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```